# Como puedo calcular un promedio con el Bucle For en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Hola chicos Buenas Tardes, quería hacer una breve consulta, necesito calcular un promedio de un array al cual no tengo visibles los enteros, se como calcularlo a nivel de aritmética, pero no se como expresarlo a código y para ello, el ejercicio me indica que debo realizar una iteración, esto es lo que llego a hacer con mi nivel de comprensión, soy nuevo en esto y llevo 3 días intentando solucionarlo, me interesa como entender la lógica y hasta ahora no eh podido conseguirlo.

Comment: en el for tenes que sumar cada valor del array acumulandolos, y fuera de el dividis ese valor por la longitud del array.

Comment: Debes editar la pregunta y colocar un ejemplo del `array`.  Además en este sitio existen usuarios que aprecian el esfuerzo, por lo que si no colocas lo que has intentado, te pueden cerrar la pregunta de todas maneras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular el promedio de un array, lo que debes hacer es sumar todos los elementos del array y dividirlo por la cantidad de elementos que tiene el array.

Hay dos formas de hacerlo:

1. En el caso del for, lo que haces es recorrer el array y sumar cada
   elemento al acumulador, luego de recorrer el array, dividas el
   acumulador por la cantidad de elementos del array.
2. En el caso de reduce, lo que haces es sumar cada elemento del array
   al acumulador, luego de recorrer el array, dividas el acumulador por
   la cantidad de elementos del array.

Ejemplo opción1 (for):

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  sum += numbers[i];
}

const average = sum / numbers.length; // 5.5

console.log(average);
```

Ejemplo opción 2 (reduce):

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const average = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / numbers.length; // 5.5

console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es algo así lo que necesitas según lo que escribes, igual creo que si puedes escribir un ejemplo estaría perfecto.

```js
const num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  sum += num[i];
}

const promedio = sum / num.length;

console.log(promedio);
```